# Hibernate Error While working on SimpleDB Database of Amazon

Tags: hibernate, grails, jpa, amazon-simpledb

I am working on a grails application which uses Amazon's SimpleDB.
I changed a domain field type from String to boolean and now my application does not start up. We are using jPA plugin for integration.
I have not changed the name of the field just the type.

My code is

```
String newsletter
```

change the above to

```
boolean newsletter = false
```

It gives me a hibernate exception

> ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error
>   creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate
>   property mapping of newsletter found in com.traveloni.User
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate
>   property mapping of newsletter found in com.traveloni.User    at
>   org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)     at
>   grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)  at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)   at
>   _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
>     at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
>     at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)    at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)   at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)   at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)     at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)    at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)  at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)  at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)  at
>   gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)     at
>   gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)  at
>   gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)   at
>   gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)   at
>   gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)    at
>   gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)   at
>   gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)     at
>   gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate
>   property mapping of newsletter found in com.traveloni.User    ... 23
>   more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate
>   property mapping of newsletter found in com.traveloni.User    ... 23
>   more Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property
>   mapping of newsletter found in com.traveloni.User     ... 23 more

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Ok. My application is up now. Wasted the whole day on it and just tried Boolean instead of boolean and it worked. Dont know why it should not work because in grails everything is an object but still . Any ideas , do post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Boolean` instead of `boolean`.
   It worked .